Delphi Firemonkey TTabControl prevent left and right arrow key
I'm using Delphi firemonkey TTabControl.  I want to prevent the left and right arrow key from changing the tabs.  I want to just allow Ctrl-Tab and Ctrl-Shift-Tab (which I feel is normal behavior.
In VCL, I think can override TTabControl OnKeyDown, which will create an inherited control (and hence installation of a custom control), are there any other methods to ignore this left and right arrow changing the TAB as it is annoying?
procedure TCustomTabControl.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key in [VK_LEFT, VK_RIGHT] then
    Exit; // Prevent the default behavior for left and right arrow keys
  inherited KeyDown(Key, Shift);
end;

In FireMonkey, however there is no KeyDown for TTabControl
I checked the source code for firemonkey version of TTabItem which has an OnKeyDown which causes the left/right arrow keys to change the tabs.
procedure TTabItem.KeyDown(var Key: Word; var KeyChar: System.WideChar; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  NewTabIndex: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  if TabControl <> nil then
  begin
    if Key = vkLeft then
    begin
      NewTabIndex := FTabControl.FindVisibleTab(TTabControl.TFindKind.Back);
      if NewTabIndex <> -1 then
      begin
        FTabControl.SetTabIndexByUser(NewTabIndex);
        Key := 0;
        TabControl.GoToActiveTab;
      end;
    end
    else if Key = vkRight then
    begin
      NewTabIndex := FTabControl.FindVisibleTab(TTabControl.TFindKind.Next);
      if NewTabIndex <> -1 then
      begin
        FTabControl.SetTabIndexByUser(NewTabIndex);
        Key := 0;
        TabControl.GoToActiveTab;
      end;
    end;
    if TabControl.ActiveTab <> nil then
      TabControl.ActiveTab.SetFocus;
  end;
end;

In the form's OnKeyDown, I have tried setting
if (Key in [vkLeft,vkRight] then
begin
  Key := 0;
  Exit; // no difference
end;

In Firemonkey, is over-riding the TTabItem protected OnKeyDown the only way?
VCL form only has a KeyPreview which allows me to discard any key if unwanted.  However, this is missing in Firemonkey.
Thank you.

The arrow keys only do that when the tab top has focus. Set CanFocus to false for each tab and no focus no arrow key changing tabs.

@Brian Your solution also breaks the ability to use Ctrl-Tab and Ctrl-Shift-Tab to move between tabs.

If a tab has at least one focusable control Ctrl-Tab and Ctrl-Shift-Tab work as unhandled  keys are passed up the control hierarchy. An extra press is required if no control on the tab is focused - the first press will focus a control and then next will switch tabs.

@Brian Thank you. Previously I set the Tabstop=False for all the TTabItems.  The CanFocus works.  Just that the Ctrl-Tab and Ctrl-Shift-Tab is a bit erratic depending on what controls are on the TabItem. Wish that original design is to be able to enable/disable a single keystroke of Tab being able to change Tab. A AlwaysRequireCtrlKey type of property will be nice.
